# Correct Cache-Control header for appcache

Tags: web, caching, http-headers, cache-control

I have trouble figuring out a cache-control header for delivering files that are used for an HTML5 app that uses the AppCache, which works on all major browsers(Chrome/Safari, Opera, Firefox, IE10).

The problem that I run into, is that when one kind of header works for a certain browser, another one may break completely. For example:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

Works fine on Webkit browsers, and they refresh and load updated files and replace them in the cache. However Firefox and IE10 both refuse to load the new files and instead get them from the cache (not appcache!), even though they recognize the updated manifest file.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

works fine on webkit browsers also, and also makes Firefox AND IE10 load the new files, instead of loading them from their cache, but breaks offline functionality, since they essentially don't cache (as the header would tell) the files, even though they are explicitly mentioned in the appcache manifest.

Lastly, I tried

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Which works similarly to `no-cache` but instead of Firefox and IE10 not retaining the files for offline use it's Webkit that doesn't retain them.

Sending no Cache-Control header yields the same results as `private` or `public`, since I assume the browser simply assumes that as the standard way.

So what am I missing? `public` has the same results as `private` and setting a max-age is not an option since updates (including Hotfixes) are not delivered on a regular basis, but instead whenever they are available or needed.

Can someone shed a light on which Cache-Control header is the correct one to use, which will work on all browsers?

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-cache` should not work in the way you described. Actually, http://appcachefacts.info/ states: "In Firefox, any resources served with Cache-control: no-store will not be cached, even if they're explicitly included in the manifest". Did you try with the following combination? "no-cache, must-revalidate"

Comment: Not really, we deliver the files with the `private` header and pop up a message for non-webkit browsers that tells users to please empty their cache and reload the page.